# Faster than light movement and time travel simple explanation

Tags: special-relativity, causality, faster-than-light, time-travel

I've read Stephen Hawking's Briefer History of Time and when it got to time travel back at faster than light speeds it felt natural to me. However a few months later when I talked to a friend I couldn't explain it and we re-read that part and we both were a bit confused by the explanation in the book.

My friend was not that sure about time changes in moving objects at all so I've drawn this picture to him:

[image: Initial state, moving source speed is half the speed of light]

(Initial state, moving source speed is half the speed of light)

[image: After a year]

(After a year light has moved a light year for static source and half a light year for moving source + half a light year the source moved itself)

It shows that since light speed is always constant and emitter speed is not added to it, then this situation can only happen if half as much time has passed for moving object than it had for a static one.

Would it be correct then, to draw this picture with moving object moving at twice the speed of light and it would show that in this case time for it would move backwards at the same rate as for it goes forward for static object?

[image: Faster than light movement]

Admittedly I'm not at all well versed in this kind of things so I wanted to hear if I'm thinking in the right direction.

Comment: This may be true, but relativity says that this can't be. This is just a hypothesis for time travel.

Comment: @Lelouch yes, I know theoretically speaking nothing can move faster than light. I also know that theoretically moving faster than light would mean time travel back in time. I mostly just wanted to make sure that my last picture is the correct demonstration/explanation of this theory.

Comment: well, pictorially its fine i guess.

Comment: Let's take an analogy of supersonic jets. We don't hear their sounds before they've arrived (traveling backwards in time), we hear them relatively *long* after they've already left (our *slow* perception).